Intuition on the norm induced by a positive semi-definite matrix
I am reading a paper about machine learning. The notations and problem setting can be simplified as follows:
We want to learn the real parameter $\theta^{*}$. Given data point $\{(x_{1}, y_{1}) ..., (x_{t-1}, y_{t-1})\}$, the loss function (negative log likelihood) of an estimate $\theta$ is denoted by $L_{t}(\theta)$. Here $x_{i} \in X$ are questions from a known question set $X$, and $y_{i}$ are binary response variables (think about logistic regression). The total number of questions that we are allowed to sample from the question set $X$, which equals $T$, is limited/finite, so there has to be some sampling technique to better recover the parameter $\theta^{*}$.
The questions $x_{t}$ are sampled sequentially, that is, we first have $x_{1}$, and then add in some $x_{2}$, then $x_{3}$, and so on. The paper says that, for an estimate $\hat{\theta_{t}}$, calculated by minimizing the loss $L_{t}(\theta)$, the matrix $H_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}})$ describes a confidence ellipsoid around the unknow parameter $\theta^{*}$, where $H_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}}) := \nabla^{2}L_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}})+\lambda I$. Also, the norm induced by the inverse of $H_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}})$, $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{H_{t}^{-1}(\hat{\theta_{t}})}$ is used to add in the new sampled question $x_{t}$.
Specifically, having $\{x_{1}, ..., x_{t-1}\}$, we calculate $\hat{\theta_{t}}$ and $H_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}})$. We then select the new question $x_{t}$ that in some sense maximizes the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{H_{t}^{-1}(\hat{\theta_{t}})}$.
Here are my questions. 1, I know the equation $x^{T}Ax = c$ or $x^{T}A^{-1}x = c$ describe an ellipsoid, but how does the matrix $H_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}})$, or its inverse, indicate a "confidence ellipsoid" (I think it's similar to a confidence interval?) around the true parameter? What is the intuition here? What is the intuition behind the Hessian matrix of the loss? 2, why do we select the new sample $x_{t}$ that maximizes that norm? Again what is the intuition here? 3, why use the norm induced by $H_{t}^{-1}(\hat{\theta_{t}})$, instead of $H_{t}(\hat{\theta_{t}})$?
Here is the original paper. It shouldn't be hard for mathematicians but I don't want to bother you to read. https://openreview.net/pdf/1d8713daf62b55267b60442e99b24068ab5053a9.pdf
